# How to send args parameters in method TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, args

I have some TypeScript method that looks like this:

```
createSomeData(args: { data: Data, helpfulInfo?: Info, context?: UIContext }): Promise<IDataModel>;
```

And main problem is I can't call it.
I tried to use Array or Turple, but I can't call it.

```
SomeClass.createSomeData(mydata, myhelpfulinfo); //error
```

What can I do in this sutation?

Comment: If you want multiple arguments, then don't declare `args` as a single object. Otherwise, you need to pass a single object into the function, not multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let args: { data: Data, helpfulInfo?: Info, context?: UIContext } = {data: mydata, helpfulInfo: myHelpfulInfo, context: myUiContext};

SomeClass.createSomeData(args);
```

**OR**

```
SomeClass.createSomeData({data: mydata, helpfulInfo: myHelpfulInfo, context: myUiContext});
```

**OR**

```
createSomeData(data: Data, helpfulInfo?: Info, context?: UIContext): Promise<IDataModel>;
```

And call it like this.

```
SomeClass.createSomeData(mydata, myhelpfulinfo);
```